# Unable to access getText() method in Appium, Node.Js

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to test the android application using Appium. I want to read the value of the textview but I am unable to do so. I get **getText() is not a function error**.
Following is my capabilities and code:

```
 const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
 const assert = require('chai').assert;

 const options = {
    capabilities: {
        platformName: 'Android',
        automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
        deviceName: 'Android',
        app: "some.apk",
        appWaitActivity: 'com.example.HomeActivity',
        autoGrantPermissions: true,
        autoAcceptAlerts: true,
        fullReset: true,
      },
       host: '0.0.0.0',
       port: 4723
   };


 describe('Start Test', function() {

     let client;
     before(async function() {
         client = await webdriverio.remote(options);
     });

     it('get text in textview', async function() {
          element = await client.findElement('id', "com.example:id/screenMsg"); // element is the textView
          assert.isNotNull(element);

          console.log(element); 

       /* In the console, I get something like this
          { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '96ec3f2a-7378-4920-a59f- c43a62bc7a44',
          ELEMENT: '96ec3f2a-7378-4920-a59f-c43a62bc7a44' }
          It means the textView is identified.
        */

         value = await element.getText(); // TypeError: element.getText() is not a function.

         console.log(value);
    });


});
```

Comment: show whole test

Comment: I have added the whole code. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any capabilities that I should add to be able to access the methods of Appium?

Comment: Finally, I am able to get the text using getElementText(). For more detail, https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#getelementtext

Answer (score 0):

Just call `text()` method to retrieve value

```
const value = await element.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute in the WebdriverIO options is `hostname` and not "`host`".
See [Options · WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html).